# Mgt-Login not firing a loginCompleted event

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

I've got an mgt-login component working fine in a page, but I can't seem to get the loginCompleted event to fire, using the following:

```
        document.querySelector('mgt-login').addEventListener('loginCompleted', e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
```

The "addEventListener" line is getting hit, but I can't seem to get it to do the console.log, nor is a breakpoint hit. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your syntax, rather it seems like this event isn't working property. The Provider state upon login initialization is returning `signedOut` and results in the following event:

`this.fireCustomEvent('loginFailed');`

instead. If you can please create an issue on the [repository](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/new/choose) with the bug details, we'll handle this within the next possible release.

Comment: Logged as bug: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/609 . Thanks Nic